# Schauerlich, schrecklich, entsetzlich, grässlich, grausam, grausig, grauenhaft - wo liegen die Unterschiede

Tags: difference, adjective, synonym

All diese Adjektive haben anscheinend eine ähnliche Bedeutung, nämlich "Entsetzen hervorrufen":

> **schrecklich**: durch seine Art, sein Ausmaß Schrecken, Entsetzen auslösend
>
> **schauerlich** (=schaurig): Schauder, Entsetzen erregend; grausig
>
> **gruselig**: Grusel hervorrufend; schaurig
>
> **grässlich**: (emotional) schauderndes Erschrecken hervorrufend
>
> **entsetzlich**: durch seine [nicht für möglich gehaltene] Furchtbarkeit bei jemandem Entsetzen erregend
>
> **grauenhaft**: Grauen hervorrufend

Quelle: Duden

Welche Unterschiede gibt es zwischen diesen Wörtern? Oder sind es Synonyme?

Comment: Why is it too broad? All the words `Grauen`, `Gruseln` , are explained using the word `Entsetzen`. It's why it's impossible for me to find a difference

Comment: Man kann bei 7 Wörtern 6+5+4+3+2+1 Vergleiche bilden, also 20 Stück insgesamt. Soviel Zeit habe ich nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Die Unterschiede sind recht fein, das stimmt. Allerdings hast du mit deinen Erklärungen dahinter bereits deine Antwort. Die Wörter unterscheiden sich der Hinsicht, dass sie jeweils eine andere Empfindung hervorrufen, z.B. Grauen oder Schrecken. Weitere inhaltlich Unterschiede gibt es hierbei nicht.

Comment: Und wie unterscheiden sich dann Grauen, Gruseln, Schrecken und Entsetzen? Grauen wird durch Gruseln erklärt, Entsetzen durch Schrecken und Grauen.