# Die Gefühle von starker Angst

Tags: difference, word-choice, synonym

Ich habe [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20561/schauerlich-schrecklich-entsetzlich-gr%C3%A4sslich-grausam-grausig-grauenhaft) nach dem Unterschied zwischen einigen Adjektiven gefragt. Die Antwort bezog sich auf einige Gefühle, zwischen denen ich auch keinen Unterschied sehe.

> **das Entsetzen:** mit Grauen und panikartiger Reaktion verbundener Schrecken
>
> **das Grauen**:
>  1. Furcht, Entsetzen vor etwas Unheimlichem, Drohendem 
>       2. grauenerregendes Ereignis
>
> **der Grusel:** Empfindung des Gruselns; Angst
>
> > **gruseln**: 
> >  a. Grausen, Furcht empfinden; ängstlich schaudern; unheimlich zumute sein; erschauern 
> >         b. sich vor etwas Unheimlichem, Makabrem o. Ä. fürchten; Grausen, Furcht empfinden
>
> **das Grausen:** Schauder und Entsetzen; Grauen (1)

Die Wörter werden miteinander erklärt. Gibt es einen Unterschied dazwischen? Habe ich Recht, dass die oben genannte Wörter viel stärker als Angst, Furcht oder Schrecken sind?

Comment: Als ich den Titel der Frage las (»Die Gefühle von starker Angst«) erwartete ich, dass unter anderem nach *Panik* gefragt wird. Nun wundere ich mich darüber, dass das nicht der Fall ist.

Comment: *Panik* ist *panika* auf Polnisch, *panic* auf Englisch. Deshalb ist *Panik* hier nicht - es hat ein 1:1 Äquivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Entsetzen** beschreibt nicht nur Angst, sondern allgemein die Reaktion auf konkrete Situationen oder Begebenheiten, die eine Person erschüttert, geschockt und/oder sprachlos zurücklassen. Auch Politiker verwenden dieses Wort gern im Zuge von Skandalen.

  > "Ich bin entsetzt über solch unerhörtes Verhalten."
  >   Mit Entsetzen stellte er fest, dass der Biervorrat leer war.
- **Grauen** ist eine starke Form von Angst, vergleichbar mit dem Horror oder der Urangst (*primal  fear*). Sie ergreift eine Person beim Anblick von  abstoßenden, widernatürlichen Dingen. *Das Grauen* kann aber im Gegensatz zu *das Grausen* auch die Sache bezeichnen, welche die Angst verursacht. (siehe zweites Beispiel)

  > Grauenhafter Fund am Autobahnzubringer - Frau zerstückelt aufgefunden!
  >   Das Grauen aus der Tiefe  (generischer Horror-Filmtitel)
  >   "Diese Musik ist ja grauenvoll!"
- **Grausen** wird meiner Meinung nach fast synonym zu *Grauen* verwendet mit der Ausnahme, dass es etwas veraltet wirkt und nicht auch Dinge beschreiben kann, welche die Angst verursacht.

  > Den Vater grauset's, er reitet geschwind.  ("Der Erlkönig")
- **Grusel** schließlich ist - wie schon andere erwähnt haben - die harmlose Variante von *Grauen*, die meist mit Geistergeschichten assoziiert wird. Der Grusel ist mehr eine Stimmung als ein Gefühl.

  > "Ganz schön gruselig hier unten, was?"

Answer (score 2):

Das **Entsetzen** ist ein Gefühl, das sich einstellen kann, ohne dass man Angst haben muss. Man ist *entsetzt*, wenn etwas passiert, mit dem man überhaupt nicht gerechnet hat, das undenkbar schlecht ist oder dergleichen.

> Mit **Entsetzen** betrachtete sie das Chaos, das das Kind angerichtet hatte.
>
> Ich bin **entsetzt,** dass Sie dem Fahrgast die Tür vor der Nase zugemacht haben, und ohne ihn losgefahren sind.

Entsetzen ist ein plötzlich auftretendes Gefühl, das sich an einem bestimmten Ereignis festmacht.

---

Das **Grauen** ist ein unspezifisches »Hintergrundgefühl«. Wenn man zum Beispiel nachts durch einen dunklen Wald geht, kann man *Grauen* empfinden; man weiß nicht genau, was einem Angst macht – es könnten Wölfe im Gebüsch lauern oder Räuber hinter den Bäumen – aber die ganze Situation ist definitiv furchteinflößend.

> Mir **graut** es davor, nachts durch den Wald zu gehen.
>
> Das Klappern der Fensterläden, das Rascheln der Blätter und das scheinbar zufällige Knarzen der Holzbalken löste in ihm **Grauen** aus.

---

Der **Grusel** lässt sich am besten anekdotisch erklären: Es gab da einmal jemanden, der sich vor nichts fürchtete, und in die Welt hinauszog, um das Gruseln zu lernen. Das Märchen geht so weiter, dass niemand ihm Angst einjagen konnte, aber zuletzt liegt er im Bett, schläft selig, und seine Frau leert einen Kübel kalten Wassers mit ein paar Fischen über ihm aus; die Kälte und das Zappeln der Fische jagt ihm einen kalten Schauder über die Wirbelsäule, und er freut sich, da er sich endlich gegruselt hat.

Außerdem ist das Gruseln von den bisherigen Begriffen am positivsten besetzt: Man erzählt sich nachts bei Kerzenschein *Gruselgeschichten*. Die Geschichten jagen einem zwar ein bisschen Angst ein, aber es ist nicht schlimm, es ist gewollt, es geht um das Kitzeln, den Schauer im Rücken. Niemand würde sich freiwillig entsetzen und auch sich zu grauen meidet man eher.

---

**Grausen** ist für mich, wie auch für Hans Adler, eine Nebenform von Grauen, die ich weitgehend bedeutungsgleich verwenden würde. Ich bin sicher, dass jemand, sofern es sie gibt, bald einen Kommentar hinterlässt, der einen Satz enthält, in dem nur eines von beiden Wörtern passt; bis dahin belasse ich es dabei.

Comment: Ich halte *Grauen* weniger für ein Hintergrundgefühl als eine sehr konkrete Reaktion auf etwas abstoßendes, "grauenvolles".

Comment: @dervonnebenaan Ich wollte damit ausdrücken, dass Grauen, im Gegensatz zu Entsetzen, welches für meine Begriffe sehr konkret und plötzlich auftritt und auch schnell wieder abebben kann, sich eher vergleichsweise langsam aufbaut und vergleichsweise länger anhält. Ich kann mich in meiner Einschätzung natürlich auch täuschen.

Answer (score 1):

Die Wörter unterscheiden sich für mein Gefühl hauptsächlich darin, ob sie ein Gefühl oder eine Situation beschreiben sowie darin, ob das, wovor man Angst hat, wahrscheinlich nie eintreten wird, noch (potenziell) bevorsteht oder bereits eingetreten ist.

- Furcht (begründete Angst, auch im Sinne von Gehorsam verwendet) und Angst (begründet oder unbegründet) beziehen sich ausschließlich auf die Gefühle von Personen.
- Grusel ist das meist im Sinne eines Nervenkitzels erwünschte und oft unbegründete Gefühl, das sich in grusligen Situationen einstellt.
- Entsetzen ist ein sich typischerweise plötzlich einstellendes Angstgefühl angesichts einer überwältigenden, aussichtslosen Situation.
- Die Abgrenzung zwischen den Wörtern Grauen und Grausen ist auch für Muttersprachler meist unklar, so dass sie weitgehend synonym verwendet werden. Sie beschreiben eine mit Angstgefühlen aufgeladene Situation oder Atmosphäre, die einen "packen" kann.
- Bei Schrecken (insbesondere den Schrecken eines Krieges) handelt es sich meist um konkrete, Entsetzen oder zumindest Angst auslösende Erlebnisse.

PS: Wie chirlu richtig angemerkt hat, müssen die Angstgefühle bei Entsetzen und Grau[s]en (und natürlich auch bei Schrecken) nicht unbedingt eigene sein. Es gibt Entsetzen und Grau[s]en über die Schrecken, die jemand anders widerfahren.

Comment: Hm, Entsetzen empfinden kann man aber sehr gut auch ohne Angst. Es muß nämlich nicht um etwas gehen, das einen selbst betrifft oder bedroht. Bei _Grauen_ ist es so ähnlich.

Comment: Entsetzen muss sich auch nicht plötzlich einstellen. Eine sich schrittweise zuspitzende Situation oder nach und nach eintreffende Informationen können auch ein ebenso sich nach und nach einstellendes Entsetzen bewirken.

Comment: @userunknown: Der Duden definiert Entsetzen als "mit Grauen und panikartiger Reaktion verbundener Schrecken". Das passt sicherlich besser zu plötzlichen Ereignissen. Das Wort wird aber inzwischen zweifellos auch allgemeiner verwendet. Deshalb habe ich die Aussage ja auch mit "typischerweise" eingeschränkt.

Comment: Wieso soll das besser passen? Wieso "inzwischen"? Wenn ich Ausschwitz besuche erwarte ich auch eine Reaktion des Entsetzens - dieses kommt aber nicht überraschend oder plötzlich. Untypisch finde ich das auch nicht. In Horrorfilmen wird das Entsetzen auch oft sukzessive aufgebaut und kommt nicht plötzlich.

Comment: Ein Besuch in Auschwitz ist in der Regel mit Grauen verbunden, aber nicht mit einer panikartigen Reaktion - es sei denn, man wusste nicht, was einen da erwartet. Wenn man sich das Wort "Entsetzen" anschaut, ist ziemlich offensichtlich, dass es ursprünglich mit einer "ent-setzenden" Bewegung zu tun gehabt haben muss (zu dem Verb s. Grimm), offensichtlich durch einen Schreck ausgelöst. Entsprechend auch die Definition bei Wiktionary: Gefühl des fassungslosen Erschreckens.

Comment: Ich habe übrigens nicht behauptet, dass Entsetzen ohne Schreck untypisch ist, sondern nur die etwas schwächere Aussage getroffen, dass Entsetzen mit Schreck typisch ist. (Das ist keine Spitzfindigkeit, genauso wie "nicht wenig", wenn es nicht als rhetorische Figur gebraucht wird, nicht "viel" impliziert.)